# Why does the 1D convolution use 3 params when the filter is 2

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

I call the Keras Conv1D function

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import Conv1D
...

X = X_input

# Stage 1
X = Conv1D(
        1,
        2,
        strides=2,
        name='conv1',
        kernel_initializer=glorot_uniform(seed=0)
        )(X)
```

And when I look at the summary it says

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 100, 1)]     0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv1D)                  (None, 50, 1)        3           input_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

My understanding is that the model will learn the values in the filter which is defined in the second argument of the Conv1D function as size 2 so why is the Param # for Conv1D in the summary 3?

Comment: I think this question is not completely off-topic at this forum. Because it needs the knowledge of how convolutional layers work rather than reading the library manuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the bias term. In convolutional layers, bias is also typically implemented. So, the number of parameters will be `filter_size + 1`.